# Error sending Emails With Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, email, email-client

I was making a email client with Visual Basic 2010

Here's the code to send the emails:

```
Try
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("********@*********".Trim(), "*************".Trim())
    SmtpServer.Port = 456
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("inviamentatoreemaille@gmail.com")
    mail.To.Add("************@******")
    mail.Subject = TextBox1.Text
    mail.Body = TextBox2.Text
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: What's your exception?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d7kujb

Comment: Please do not post errors/exceptions as an image.  Copy the text of the exception and edit your post.

Comment: Try changing port to 587.

Comment: still not working but the error changed: http://pastebin.com/9pXUhzhC

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP port for GMAIL is 465 not 456

Gmail has 2 SMTP Ports, unless you have a G-Suite account in which port 25, becomes available.

Port 465 (SSL)
Port 587 (TLS)

If you're programming at your home, most INTERNET providers block SMTP Sending ports.

So the first thing you should do is make sure you are able to connect via TELNET

Open up a command prompt and type in:

```
 telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
 telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

If you are able to connect to the telnet ports, then you should be able to get your code working to send mail through it.

Your network credentials have to be your gmail account:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("********@*********".Trim(), "*************".Trim())
```

So I'm assuming it's more like:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "Password")
```

Comment: I Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Less Secure Apps for your account.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en.

Cheers,
Radu